# Passing parameter to SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to pass a parameter to a stored procedure in my application but I don't know what I am doing wrong. I get an error

> Procedure or function 'usp_getBorrowerDetails' expects parameter '@BookID', which was not supplied.

while I am passing and I did many things but still didn't find the solution.

This is my code:

```
IDataReader reader = null;

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();

try
{
    SqlConnection connection = GetDBConnection();

    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.CommandText = Constants.SP_BookBorrowerDetails;
    command = new SqlCommand(command.CommandText, connection);

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BookID", bookID);

    reader = base.ExecuteReader(command);
}
catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
{
    throw new Exception("Oops! Something went wrong.");
}
```

Below is my stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_getBorrowerDetails]
    @BookID INT
AS
    SELECT 
        Name, Mobile, ReturnDate 
    FROM
        BorrowerDetails 
    INNER JOIN
        BookDetails ON BookDetails.CurrentBorrowerID = BorrowerDetails.ID    
    WHERE
        BookDetails.BookID = @BookID
GO
```

If I run any stored procedure that does not requires any parameter, it works fine. Issue is only coming when I am adding parameter.

Comment: Do not use AddWithValue https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: What is in `Constants.SP_BookBorrowerDetails`?

Comment: Not an answer but you really need to wrap your connection in a USING clause. As coded your connection is not being properly closed and disposed which can lead to the connection pool being consumed.

Comment: @PeterB this is not the case I changed it to bookID as well

Comment: @SeanLange The same for the SqlCommand object

Comment: @GuidoG I have used this 
 command.Parameters.Add("@BookID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = bookID;. But still getting same issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're redefining `command` to a brand new `SqlCommand` after setting the `CommandType` and `CommandText`, meaning it will be treated as plain SQL, rather than a stored procedure. Create it once in the appropriate place.

```
IDataReader reader = null;
SqlCommand command;

try
{
    SqlConnection connection = GetDBConnection();

    command = new SqlCommand(Constants.SP_BookBorrowerDetails, connection);
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BookID", bookID);

    reader = base.ExecuteReader(command);
}
catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
{
    throw new Exception("Oops! Something went wrong.");
}
```

As an aside, you should probably also look at not just keeping the connection open, but instead getting the results within the one method, rather than relying on the calling code to manage the connection.

Answer (score 4):

One of the problems is the order of your code. You are setting your command to a new SqlCommand. When this happens the default CommandType is Text.

```
command = new SqlCommand(command.CommandText, connection);
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
command.CommandText = Constants.SP_BookBorrowerDetails;
```

You should first create the command, then set the properties.

Comment: @PeterB not sure what you mean.

Comment: Sorry, first line threw me off, it says `new SqlCommand(command.CommandText ...) ` but it should use `Constants.SP_BookBorrowerDetails`

Comment: Ahh I see what you mean. I just rearranged the lines the OP posted. Not really sure why they have a Constants object to hold string values but whatever. Maybe it reads from a resx or something. Probably better to just not include it in the constructor since it is being set explicitly later. Doing it twice is kind of silly. :)

Answer (score 2):

One possibility here is that `bookID` is `null`.

`Convert.ToString(null)` returns: `null`.

A parameter with a `null` value **is not attached**. You need to use `DBNull.Value` for that.

But: there's also no need to make it a `string` *anyway*.

Consider using: `(object)bookId ?? DBNull.Value` as the value instead, which should fix both of these issues.

---

Edit: as noted in a comment, you're also setting the `CommandType` too early, and then replacing the command object; setting the `CommandType` must be done *after* you've `new`-d the variable.

---

Note: these are just two of *many* things that "dapper" would help you with; consider:

```
var reader = connection.ExecuteReader(
      "usp_getBorrowerDetails", new { BookID = bookID },
      commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

(although usually I'd advocate dapper's `Query<T>` methods instead - they do *a lot more* for you, too)

Comment: He should also set the commandtype and text after creating a new command, not before

Comment: I updated code and removed convert.ToString. Still getting same issue

Comment: @kamranLadhani see GuidoG's point there too; that's another very likely cause!

Comment: @GuidoG even more reason to prefer tools like "dapper" (see edit); you can't mess up code that you don't have to write :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have declared Constants.SP_BookBorrowerDetails as "EXEC [dbo].[usp_getBorrowerDetails]", it doesn't have the expected input parameter "@BookID".

Command.Parameters.AddWithValue which will only accepts the parameter name & value which needs to be passed.But still it would expect the parameter in the Constants.SP_BookBorrowerDetails syntax because while executing the command text the list of parameters available in the "Command.Parameters" needs the mapping parameter which has the same name.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("SQL connection string"))
        {
            connection.Open();
            try
            {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("EXEC [dbo].[usp_getBorrowerDetails] @BookID", connection);
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command = new SqlCommand(command.CommandText, connection);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BookID", 1);

                IDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Oops! Something went wrong." + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Please check above code snippet.

Please revert back if any issue arises.

Answer (score 0):

It's work for me,

```
connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
connection.Open();
SqlCommand  com  = new SqlCommand("usp_getBorrowerDetails", connection);
com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BookID", bookID);

IDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
   
}

reader.Close();
connection.Close();
```